# WebScrapping soup + python exportar para txt e verificar com shell script

Tags: python, shell, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Saudações pessoas, estou aqui com um código em python que me traz os milissegundos do ping de envio das notas fiscais eletronicas da sefaz no portal de status da NFC-e como abaixo :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import requests, lxml.html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
resp = requests.get('http://www.nfce.se.gov.br/portal/ConStatusAuto?Origem=1')
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(resp.text)
for tr in doc.xpath('//tr'):
    nome = tr[0].text_content().strip()
    print(nome.ljust(25), '|'.join('{: >7}'.format(td.text_content().strip())
        for td in tr.xpath('.//td')[1:]))
```

Até ai tudo bem, o que estou na duvida agora e não to conseguindo fazer é exportar os dados da saída do script para um arquivo txt de nome consulta.txt, e um shell script que verifique se o primeiro ping esta acima de 1s para me retornar o valor inteiro 1 ou se estiver abaixo de 1s para me retornar o valor inteiro 0. Abaixo está a saida do script que preciso que o shell consulte :

```
:/usr/src/zabbixbot# ./sefaz.py
('SEFAZ Amazonas           ', '       |  530ms|  900ms|  415ms|    0ms|  900ms|  661ms|    0ms|  806ms|   50ms|  530ms|  859ms|  676ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms')
(u'SEFAZ S\xe3o Paulo          ', '       |    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms')
(u'SEFAZ Paran\xe1             ', '       |  354ms|1s808ms|  551ms|  433ms|1s808ms|  620ms|  429ms|  799ms|  495ms|  354ms|  880ms|  507ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms')
('SEFAZ Goias              ', '       |    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms')
('SEFAZ Mato Grosso        ', '       |  503ms|  1s4ms|  317ms|  609ms|  861ms|  301ms|    0ms|  896ms|  325ms|  503ms|  1s4ms|  341ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms')
('SEFAZ Rio Grande do Sul  ', '       |  844ms|1s886ms|  974ms|  852ms|1s166ms|  964ms|  871ms|1s886ms|  986ms|  844ms| 1s79ms|  969ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms')
('SEFAZ Virtual RS         ', '       |  761ms|5s854ms|  1s2ms|  830ms|1s245ms|  964ms|  761ms|5s854ms| 1s65ms|  837ms|1s329ms|  942ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms')
('SEFAZ Mato Grosso do Sul ', '       |    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms')
(u'SEFAZ Cear\xe1              ', '       |    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms')
('SEFAZ Minas Gerais       ', '       |    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms')
('SEFAZ Pernambuco         ', '       |    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms|    0ms')
```

No caso eu só preciso verificar o SEFAZ Virtual RS que é o autorizador do meu estado, os demais podem ser desconsiderados e o primeiro ping é logo o primeiro que se encontra após o nome SEFAZ Virtual RS, ou seja neste caso 761ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro pra pegar o primeiro ping só do Virtual RS, basta fazer um if

```
for tr in doc.xpath('//tr'):
    nome = tr[0].text_content().strip()
    if nome == 'SEFAZ Virtual RS':
        valor_ping = tr[2].text_content().strip()
        break # achou, sai do for
```

Depois é só verificar:

```
valor_ping = valor_ping[:-2] # retira o `ms` que tem no final
if 's' in valor_ping:  # se tiver a letra `s` é mais que 1 segundo
     print(1)
else:
     print(0)
```

Comment: salvou minha vida amigo, mt obrigado, ele retornou o 0 corretamente, porém ele tambem ta printando todos os autorizadores e os pings, tem como ele retornar só o valor 1 ou 0 ?

Comment: Retire os outros `print`s então, @RafaelXavierSuarez - você é o programador, tente modificar o código pra fazer o que você quer